# convert web application to a web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, vs-web-site-project, vs-web-application-project

I have a c# .net VS2010 web application that contains only classic asp files.

What I want to do is convert the web application to a web site to make it easier to manage the classic asp files.

How can I convert from web application to web site? I have researched google and found lots of examples going the other way.

Comment: Why not just create a new web site and refer the virtual directory to the existing one. Then, disable the web app. If it works well, remove the web app.

Comment: @amateur May I ask why do you want to go on the opposite direction please

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an automated way to do this. You could just create a new website in Visual Studio and copy your files from the web app into this new website. Be sure to go into each and every .aspx/.ascx file and edit the 'Codebehind' attribute so that it reads 'Codefile' (codebehind directive needs to be compiled and thus won't work in an ASP.NET website). You'll also need to delete the Designer/Designer.cs files.

Hopefully you don't have too many files so that this won't be too much of a PITA.